# Cshell Script date issue

Tags: shell, date

Is there a way to add date in the name of the file... we can add current date in this manner `date '+%Y%m%d'` but i want to add "filename_date_1-2-2011_thru_31-2-2011.txt" Is it possible to do that??????????

Comment: @glenn: No, the second of Gloureber.

Comment: You question is unclear. If you just want the dates you have specified, the you can hardcode them as part of the filename, right? Do you want to dynamically append a date-range "tag" to your file name as you show in your example? Assuming that is your goal, you either need a database to calc and fmt the date values into variables, or if you using Linux you can do date arithmetic with /bin/date (from GNU). Read the man page to see how it is done. Just get the simple things working first on the command line, then start adding features like '+ 30 days' or '- 1 month', etc, etc. Good luck!

Comment: I'd advise you to stick to year-month-day format, as it sorts well (e.g. in directory listings)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sufficiently advanced version of the `date` command and you know a Unix timestamp for the start and end dates, then you can use:

- (MacOS X) `date -r 1234567890 "+%d-%m-%Y"` to obtain 13-02-2009.
- (GNU) `date -d 2/13/2009 "+%d-%m-%Y"` to obtain 13-02-2009 again.

If you don't want the leading zeroes on the day of month, then you need to use '%e` instead of '%d' on Linux (but that puts a space in place of the zero). It is not clear that there's a format specifier for day-of-month without a leading zero on MacOS X; nor is it clear that there's a way to format month of year as a single-digit number for January to September on either platform.

You get the format into your C shell script using back-ticks around the date commands.

Consider reading [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) and heeding its advice.